# My android app looks different on the phone than android studio

Tags: android, scrollview

My android app looks different on the phone than android studio
look at screenshot

[app in the phone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuDCd.png)

[App in the Android studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxb4Y.png)

why is that? and how can I fix that?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please include all your relevant code as text here, we can't copy your code from the image :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Sorry, I wasn't able to add the xml code here, I pasted it here https://pastebin.com/raw/qjn4ZFzZ

Comment: you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64615171/edit) your question to include it

Answer (score 1):

Your preview shows what your layout would look like on a Pixel 3, which is quite a large phone. From what I saw on your screenshot looks like your device isn't quite as large so I'd recommend you to use ConstraintLayout for 2 reasons:

1. Consistency across different screen sizes - it's much more likely your layout will look the same on a large screen and a small one
2. Better performance, especially for your case since you'll be able to do everything with a single layout, without having to nest several layouts

For more information on ConstraintLayout, please check out this [post](https://medium.com/@92alanc/the-ultimate-view-group-constraintlayout-e0598d2e1a05) I wrote on Medium

Comment: Is there a way other than using ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Well there's always a way but I strongly advise you to use it as nesting layouts is not a good practice